# Read partial socket message

Tags: java, socket

I've written some code that is suppose to read socket all the time and when needed return the partial data from it. I just want the response to send a command. It works, but this is a bit messy implementation.

Is it possible to write it better?

```
public StringBuilder message = new StringBuilder();
private BufferedReader reader;
private Socket socket;
public boolean writing = true;
public boolean wantToRead = false;

public String getMessage() {
        synchronized (message) {
            while (writing) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("waiting");
                    wantToRead = true;
                    message.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            System.out.println("take the resource");
            writing = true;
            return message.toString().substring(0, message.toString().lastIndexOf("\n"));
        }
    }

@Override
    public void run() {
        int c;
        try {
            while((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                synchronized(message) {
                    message.append(Character.toString((char) c));
                    if(!reader.ready()) {
                        System.out.println("end of response");
                        if(wantToRead) {
                            writing = false;
                            wantToRead = false;
                            message.notify();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println("zamykam socket");
            socket.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Instead of reading one character at a time, try the other BufferedReader methods that read many characters in one read.
- Don't synchronize on actual useful objects since those objects might have some locks on them elsewhere, or internally.  Either create some `Object lock`, or even better is to use a real lock from java.util.concurrent.locks.
- You don't need `if(!reader.ready())`.  It's the exact same condition as the end of the while-loop.  Just put that code after the while loop.  You can synchronize again.
- `writing` and `wantToRead` should definitely be `volatile` since you use them in different threads.  Also, you should probably rename them because it is not obvious what they are supposed to do.
- Actually, **don't use either synchronized, wait/notify or locks**.  Those are primitive constructs from the early versions of Java.  They have been replaced by the modern patterns in [java.util.concurrent](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/io/BufferedReader.html) about a decade ago (see [Java Concurrency in Practice (2006)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321349601)).  It's very hard to avoid (nearly undetectable) bugs when using the old constructs.  You can look at [BlockingQueue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) and Future as examples of the new concurrency classes.
- Don't use threads, but Executors (also in java.util.concurrent).

---

Here is a rewrite of your code with a BlockingQueue:

```
private static final String MESSAGE_SEPARATOR = ">";
    private final BlockingQueue<String> blockingQueue = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();
    BufferedReader reader; // TODO init somewhere

    /**
     * Blocking method.
     */
    public String takeNextMessage() throws InterruptedException {
        return blockingQueue.take();
    }

    public void startReceivingMessages() {
        Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().submit(() -> {
            try {
                String fullMessage = "";
                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    if (line.startsWith(MESSAGE_SEPARATOR)) {
                        if (!fullMessage.isEmpty())
                            blockingQueue.put(fullMessage);
                        fullMessage = "";
                    }
                    fullMessage += line;                        
                }
                if (!fullMessage.isEmpty())
                    blockingQueue.put(fullMessage);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }
```

I hope you can appreciate how hugely simpler this is.  It's not just that it is shorter, but that there is absolutely no reasoning to do about which variable in which thread has to be synchronized, and how and where does variables, or code blocks, should synchronize.  With the modern constructs, there is no need to use `synchronized`, `wait/notify`, `volatile`, or `xxxx.lock()` in the vast majority of problems.  The code is much much easier to read and reason about.

Comment: I need the code if(!reader.ready()) because i need to detect when the loop will block at reader.read(). My socket stream is almost always on so the loop will only end on crash. When connected and reading i'll be always in loop, and i need to know when the response ends. And reader.ready() can say me that the reader will block only on reader.read() so i cannot use readline() etc.

Comment: OK, I understand your problem better now.  You definitely want to use a [BlockingQueue<String>](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) which takes in sentences.

Comment: I also added an item in my answer about `writing` and `wantToRead`.

Comment: That's great but still i need to read multiline resposnses and know when there is the end of message. I pass the command to the socket, need to wait for reader to read the response and then take it. As you can see i update a question with my rewroted code. I put to the queue only if the reader read the full message, while take waits for it. I'm also not sure about executor i use.

Comment: From what I understand from the doc, `!in.ready()` is equivalent to `in.read() == -1`.  So it looks to me that you will read a single message.  Also, I would not make the queue of capacity 1, since you can than accumulate messages without blocking.

Comment: !in.ready() means that next read() will block. in.read() == 1 means that socet connection is closed by the other side so the stream has ended. In my code it'll read until it blocks (no data to recive but connection still open) but before block it'll put whole readed message to queue.

Comment: Your updated code is not the same as your original code: your messages are not `\n` delimited anymore.

Comment: I'm not sure it does what you want: if two messages arrive in very close succession, they will be sent together as a single message.  If you want to add a delimiter, you'll get back to my solution, which is a lot simpler.

Comment: The thing is that the response is NOT one line message ended with "\n" delimeter. The resposne for each command can be one line or multilined. As i can see every response is ended with line starting with ">" character but not ended with "\n". Something like input prompt for next command. For now i don't know how to handle this resposnes and how to make get wait for the resposnse to be read. I need somehow to match command sended with response recived.

Comment: I updated my code sample.  It assumes a message starts with ">" and is composed of many lines, each (including the first line with ">") terminating with `\n`.

Answer (score 5):

You are locking on a public field `message` which might cause a `deadlock`. If locking is needed, then do it on a `private` field.

```
private final Object SYNC_OBJECT = new Object();
...
synchronized(SYNC_OBJECT){
}
```

Your class extends `Thread` apparently, and the rule is : favor composition over inheritance.

```
  private Runnable runnable;

  public void startListening(){
    // use the runnable
  }
```

Moreover, you barely need to use threads, use [Executors instead](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> return message.toString().substring(0, message.toString().lastIndexOf("\n"));
> ```

`message` is a `StringBuilder` and `StringBuilder` has both `substring(beginIndex, endIndex)` and `lastIndexOf(str)` as well, so you could omit the `toString()` calls. The following is the same:

```
return message.substring(0, message.lastIndexOf("\n"));
```

Furthermore, I'd create an explanatory local variable for the result to explain what is its purpose and make reading/maintenance easier:

```
String messageBeforeLastLineBreak = message.substring(0, message.lastIndexOf("\n"));
return messageBeforeLastLineBreak;
```

(*Clean Code* by *Robert C. Martin*, *G19: Use Explanatory Variables*;  *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code by Martin Fowler*, *Introduce Explaining Variable*)

Be aware, that `lastIndexOf()` could return `-1` when there is no `\n` in the message and you'll get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. I guess you should handle that case too. (If it's an error of the client throw an exception which says that this is a client error, it would help debugging.)